# How to specify a region for Google App Engine instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

When authorizing a `Cloud SQL` instance for an `App Engine` instance, it is required to have both instances in the same region - this is stated by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/) as below snapshot.

[image]

The issue is that we can choose the region for a `Cloud SQL` instance when creating it, though I'm not sure how we can choose one for [creating/uploading an `App Engine` instance](https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine?_ga=1.58461994.1847533684.1404529462)

[image]

So the question is, how to specify a region for App Engine instance?

Answer (score 5):

Europe is available for App Engine apps, currently on a limited basis and by request.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/location
http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/12/app-engine-174-released.html
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1W7LsnYRj0eBAzEQlDtFbsVuIZ0nFU2TaP7cZiaY4Z0Q/viewform?formkey=dDllb3FHLS1IdXVIcjVKR3FScklka1E6MQ

App Engine is just in the United States and Europe for now.

Previously on Stack Overflow: [Verify/change application region at Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766488/region-at-google-app-engine) [Change GAE application location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589246/change-gae-application-location)

Comment: Yeah. That's why when I choose Asia to be my instance's region, it is said the storage instance not in the same region with my app engine instance (which is in Europe/USA only)

Comment: May you help to explain what are your 03 links is about?

Comment: The first link explains the others: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/location If you want to request to move your app to the EU region, click the "European Offering request form" link at the bottom of that page.  Unfortunately, App Engine is not yet available in the Asia region.

Comment: I wasn't able to make the EU region work (for App Engine instances), just moved the Cloud SQL to United States

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question 3.5 years later, and `gcloud` now supports creating App Engine applications for a project in a particular region:

```
$ gcloud app create --project=$PROJECTID --region=northamerica-northeast1
```

Alternatively it can be specified in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine) when creating a project's *App Engine* component.