# How may I change GAE App Engine location for an existing app?

Tags: google-app-engine

Title says it all.

Note: No answer found at [Verify/change application region at Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766488/verify-change-application-region-at-google-app-engine?s=1|4.2951)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change GAE application location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589246/change-gae-application-location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no :( You have to create a new project.